# What does "re-entry stamp" in this sentence mean?

Tags: resident-permit, non-residents, kenya

"re-entry stamp in passport valid minimum 3 months after expiry of the visa"

what does re-entry stamp in this sentence mean?

Comment: What jurisdiction?

Comment: www.vfsglobal.com/italy/kenya/familyrenuion_documents.html

Comment: Good question!  It's poorly worded and seems to say the opposite of what I assume it ought to say.

Comment: I'm confused, I have been trying all day but I couldn't understand!

Comment: Are you in Kenya now, and without a residence permit?

Comment: I'm a Somali citizen, and most of EU states embassies competent for Somalia are in Nairobi because of that they don't require Somali citizens to have Kenyan residence permit, and most of them don't even recognize the Somali passport so they don't care whether you are legally present or not as long as you have the visa documents, but the Italian embassy recognized the Somali ePassport as valid and I want to apply a tourist visa there, they don't require a residence permit for Somalis as well, but the thing I couldn't understand is that 're-entry stamp' I will be going to Nairobi soon!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This provision probably does not apply to you, since you are a Somali citizen (as you have indicated in the comments).

The provision, I just now realized, seems to be designed to ensure two things: First, that the applicant is legally resident in Kenya, and second, that the applicant will be able to return to Kenya after the expiration of the Schengen visa.  (That is, I suspect that the "visa" referred to in "minimum 3 months after the expiry of the visa" is the visa *for which you are applying.*)

For those resident in Somalia, the facts of residence and admissibility presumably need to be proved with respect to Somalia rather than Kenya.  As a Somali citizen, you obviously require no residence permit or visa or other passport stamp before being admitted to Somalia, so you should probably just ignore this item on the list.

Of course, a zealous and ill-informed employee of the consulate or of VFS Global might not understand the reasoning I've just outlined (if it is indeed correct).  I therefore suggest that you ask someone whether that list item applies to you, or if you should substitute something else.  If they say that you need to provide a residence permit or show a stamp, explain your situation and why those things do not apply to you.